# Shortcode to return an image based on post taxonomy

Tags: shortcode

here is my first question here !

I learn a lot reading question an answers here, but I still have a lot more to learn...

So, I want to create a simple shortcode, to return an image "If this taxonomy"

I think I am missing something obvious with the "Qwery"

Here's my code :

```
<?php 

function fun_set_taxo_image($post_id) {

    if ( have_posts() ) {

        while ( have_posts() ) {

            the_post(); 

            if( has_term($post_id, 'term-name_a', 'my_taxo' ) ) {

                return "The image A";

            } elseif ( has_term($post_id, 'term-name_b', 'my_taxo' ) ) {

                return "The image B";

            }

        }

}

add_shortcode('taxo_image', 'fun_set_taxo_image');

?>
```

I want to insert the shortcode in a grid post based, to identify each post with a little
image depending of taxonomy... When I insert other shortcodes like `[acf field="field_name" post_id="%post_id%"]` is work well, the shortcode return any data related with the post...

So, hope somebody can helpmeet with this...

Thanks guys

Comment: Yo! @cybmeta thanks for the edit ! Sorry, I try to envelope my code a few times, pero nunca lo logré...!!!

Answer (score 1):

There's no need to replicate The Loop in your plugin; WordPress is working within a post when it processes a shortcode, so the post ID is available when the shortcode is being processed.

Also, your arguments for has_term are out of order. And finally, it's a best practice to make a shortcode all one word.

```
function fun_set_taxo_image( $atts, $content = null ) {
    global $post;

    if( has_term( 'term_name_a', 'my_taxo', $post->ID ) ) {
        return "image A";
    }
    else {
        return "image B";
    }
}

add_shortcode( 'taxoimage', 'fun_set_taxo_image' );
```

Comment: Hi Doug, thanks a lot for your answer and advices. I test your code as you wrote here, and is not working (of course, I change the "term_names") but is always returning "image B" even if has "term_name_a"... I think the solution is not so far... What do you think about??

Comment: @MicoLoco I think the problem is the scope of the post itself within the function. I have updated my code, see if this works.

Comment: Thanks again dude, but that still always returning "Image B"... I try too `global $wp_post_types;
$obj = $wp_post_types['movie'];` cause I'm working with PostType... Important info: when I insert the shortcode `[taxoimage]` in a post, is work fine ! But when I insert in the a post grid item (there where I need) is always returning "Image B". I think the function is scoping the main page and not the post item ;(

Comment: @MicoLoco My last try is this edited answer.

Comment: Thanks for help and all your try, but is still not working... I'll take more time to see how I can make this work. Cheers Dude!